# PHP Regex tweet Filter

Tags: php, sql, regex, postgresql, filter

i have a question.
Im crawling a twitter profile, using Rstudio,Postgreql,PHP

Im trying to filter tweets from a twitter profile.

Im using php with postgresql . I already have the tweets in a table on my website using SQL Query. I would like to use Regex to filter the tweets. I dont want to show all of the tweets from the twitter profile on my website, just some, like tweets containing #Vertraging. Now i see all of the tweets on my website.

How can i exclude all the tweets not containing #vertraging?

see screenshot for my table on my website

http://prntscr.com/384y5m

Comment: How about `if (strpos($tweet, '#vertraging') === FALSE) { ... }`?

Answer (score 0):

You can go 2 ways.
Or you filter them out before sending them to your database. In that case you could use:

```
if (preg_match('/\#vertraging/i', $tweet)
{
    //Insert in DB
}
```

If you want to insert all of them, but only select the ones with `#vertraging` from your database, you can use this `WHERE` clause in your query

```
WHERE `tweetsText' LIKE '%#vertraging%'
```

Comment: I agree, but user asked specifically for a regex

Comment: Whoops, fair enough. Missed that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Postgresql, you can ignore Regex and use straight `like` instead. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM `tweets_table` WHERE `tweet_content` LIKE '%#Vertraging%'
```

That should be as performant as regex and probably more. Hope that helps! If you're worried about uppercase/lowercase, there are two different things you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM `tweets_table` WHERE LOWER(`tweet_content`) LIKE '%#vertraging%'
```

or you can use `similar to`. However, I'd just use the `lower` alternative.

```
SELECT * FROM `tweets_table` WHERE `tweet_content` SIMILAR TO '%#(Vertraging|vertraging)%'
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: hey thank you alot, but where do i put that code? in Postgresql or in the .php file? 

see screenshots

http://prntscr.com/38573m 

http://prntscr.com/38579m

Comment: You'd add it to your `.php` file. Can you post a sample of the code you're using to access the data? Maybe I could help you with integrating it.