# Regex PHP tweet filter separate into columns

Tags: php, regex, postgresql, twitter, rstudio

I'm working on my school project about showing public transport delays in a table on my website.

I'm crawling a twitter profile, using Rstudio, Postgreql, PHP, cmd

I'm trying to filter tweets from a twitter profile(public transport profile, showing delays etc.). twitter.com/TotalOVNL

I'm using php with postgresql . I already have the tweets in a table on my website using SQL Query see link for screenshot http://prntscr.com/385squ . I would like to use Regex to filter the tweettext. I dont want to show all of the tweets' text from the tweet, just the ones containg delays and seperate it into few collumns. Ive made in paint an example of the table that i would like to have on my website, see the link for screenshot http://prntscr.com/3866u6.

I know that i have to use regex, but dont know the language that well.

Would someone be able to help me?

Comment: Screenshots are no good. One cannot copy/paste from them. Please provide example values and example results.

Comment: Also, how is this related to your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941755/php-regex-tweet-filter

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a pattern in the last two (pt number and delay).

I tried to find the best pattern matching possible, hope this helps. Look at the match groups in the bottom right to find the matches.

```
#(\w+)\s#(\w+)\sis op (\d+-\d+)\s(\d+:\d+) (\w+)lijn
```

Example on some of the tweets on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jR3vC4).

Comment: hi, thank you very much, this helped me alot but im fairly new with the website and dont know how to make the patterns.
 could you find the patterns in these ?

#OV #Vertraging #Alkmaar is op 04-08 16:20 Buslijn 2 + - 5 min. vertraging 

#OV #Vertraging #Beesd is op 04-08 14:20 trein Geen treinverkeer tussen Beesd - Leerdam 

 #OV #Vertraging #Utrecht is op 04-08 13:18 trein er rijden minder treinen tussen Utrecht-Breukelen 

i would like to have pattern of Beesd , date time , trein/bus and Geen treinverkeer tussen beesd - leerdam as comment

Comment: How about this? http://regex101.com/r/bE3jC2
There doesn't seem to be a pattern in the last sentences / timings.

Comment: how can i make a loop that it controls the pattern on every record in my database
and after the filter put it in new columns( like this http://prntscr.com/3866u6) , im using postgesql btw